# Thread-safe HashMap access

Tags: thread-safety, hashmap, synchronized

I have a class which wraps up a map. The map is read/written by an Add() and isUpwardTrade() methods as indicated below.

Do you see any thread safety issues by synchronizing the whole methods?
How would you change the following implementation (i.e. would you use a concurrentHashMap or something else? ) to improve the  performance in a multi-threaded context?

```
private Map<String, List<Double>> priceTable = new HashMap<String, List<Double>>();
private AutoTrader autoTrader;

public PriceTable(AutoTrader autoTrader) {
    this.autoTrader = autoTrader;
}

public synchronized void add(Price price) {     
    if (!priceTable.containsKey(price.getProductName())){
        List<Double> prices = new ArrayList<Double>();
        Double pValue = price.getPrice();
        prices.add(pValue);
        priceTable.put(price.getProductName(), prices);
    }else{
        Double pValue = price.getPrice();
        priceTable.get(price.getProductName()).add(pValue);
    }

    if (isUpwardTrend(price, priceTable)) {
        notifyAutoTrader(price);
    }
}

private void notifyAutoTrader(Price price) {
     autoTrader.onUpwardTrendEvent(price);
}

private synchronized boolean  isUpwardTrend(Price price, Map<String, List<Double>>   pricesTable) {
    List<Double> prices = priceTable.get(price.getProductName());
    if ( prices.size() >= 4){
        if ( calcAvg(prices)  > prices.get(prices.size() - 4) ) 
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap is not threadsafe. 
You should use ConcurrentHashMap or Hashtable.

Comment: Sure but I am synchronizing the methods that read/write the map.

Comment: I see. Since the only methods that access the HashMap are synchronized, your code is safe. If you were using a thread safe object like Hashtable, the synchronization would be implemented in the object. Your code implements the synchronization in the wrapper.